# Перевести координаты в Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, геолокация

Фактически стоит такая задача: имеются координаты (latitude и longitude) нескольких точек из Google Maps. Нужно вычислить расстояния между этими точками в метрах. Насколько я понимаю нужно преобразовать координаты в метрические - как это сделать? Меня интересует не софт, а алгоритм и формулы, чтобы я мог внедрить их с собственную программу.

Comment: @makskovalko, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

Подключаем:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

И считаем (latLngA, latLngB - объекты типа "LatLng"):

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (latLngA, latLngB);
```

Ежели использование готоых велосипедов - не для Вас и Вы решили пойти по пути истинного самурая, то есть еще один способ. Расстояние по [ортодромии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) можно рассчитать с использованием формулы [синус-верзус](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Haversine.html):

```
rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}

distHaversine = function(p1, p2) {
  var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km
  var dLat  = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
  var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = R * c;

  return d.toFixed(3);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло!